# Dynamic Input Fields in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular 8.X project and I am trying to create some HTML input fields (mostly of type Select (ng-select)) on button click. I am using ngModel.

For easy reference please find the code below -- (HTML)

```
    <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let sorting of sortingArray; let i=index">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Sort By</label>
        <ng-select class="select-sm" [items]="sortings" name="sorting" bindLabel="sort_title_face"
          bindValue="sort_title" placeholder="Sort By" [(ngModel)]="sortBy[sorting]">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Sort Order</label>
        <ng-select class="select-sm" [items]="sortingOrder" name="sortingOrder" bindLabel="sort_order_face"
          bindValue="sort_order" placeholder="Sort Order" [(ngModel)]="sortOrder[sorting]">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-link mtop-15" (click)="removeColumn(i);" *ngIf="i!=0"><i class="fa fa-times"
          aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-link mtop-15" (click)="addColumn(i)"
        *ngIf="i==sortingArray.length-1 && sortingArray.length < 4">+ Add another Sort
        Column</button>
      </div>
```

TypeScript

```
sortingArray: Array<any> = [0];
  sortBy: Array<any> = [];
  sortOrder: Array<any> = [];
  sortings: Array<any> = [
    { sort_title_face: 'Test Case', sort_title: 'test_case_name' },
    { sort_title_face: 'Probe', sort_title: 'probe_name' },
    { sort_title_face: 'Last Published', sort_title: 'published_date' },
    { sort_title_face: 'Last Un-Published', sort_title: 'unpublished_date' }
  ];
  sortingOrder: Array<any> = [
    { sort_order_face: 'Asc (A-Z)', sort_order: 'asc' },
    { sort_order_face: 'Desc (Z-A)', sort_order: 'desc' }
  ]
Search() {
    this.filter.pagination.pageNum = 1;
    this.filter.pagination.currentPage = 1
    if (this.sortBy.length && this.sortOrder.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.sortingArray.length; i++) {
        if (this.sortBy[i] && this.sortOrder[i])
          this.filter.sort_by.push(`${this.sortOrder[i]}(${this.sortBy[i]})`)
      }
    }

    this.search.emit();
    this.filter.sort_by = []
  }

  addColumn(index) {
    if (this.sortingArray.length > 3) {
      return;
    }
    let num = index + 1;
    this.sortingArray.push(num);
    console.log(this.sortingArray);
    console.log('Sortt', this.sortBy);
  }

  removeColumn(index) {
    this.sortingArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.sortBy.splice(index, 1);
    this.sortOrder.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

[Here is output snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHx7P.png)

The issue is that, when I select fields from the dropdown, it get bind with the model, but when I press the add button, my input (text) suddenly disappears, but properties are still bind with the model.
Please help me in resolve this issue.